# Type mismatch for addition of multidimension array

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array

I tried to add 2 four-dimensional array together and I have the error of type mismatch; found: Unit required: Array[Array[Array[Array[Double]]]]

Here is my code

```
val a = Array.ofDim[Int](3,1,4,2)
val b = Array.ofDim[Double](4,1,5,3) 

var c : Array[Array[Array[Array[Double]]]] = Array()

c = (a zip b).map{ case (x,y) => x + y }
```

edit: corrected syntax = to : 
sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're creating multi-dimensional arrays without any content.

Consider the following.

```
val x = Array.ofDim[Char](21)
x.length      // res0: Int = 21
x.head.toInt  // res1: Int = 0
```

This creates an `Array[Char]` with 21 empty (or zero-initialized) elements.

Also, when you zip 2 4-dim arrays you get an array of tuples, each containing  2 3-dim arrays.

```
val a = Array.ofDim[Int](3,1,4,2)
val b = Array.ofDim[Double](4,1,5,3)
a zip b  // res0: Array[(Array[Array[Array[Int]]], Array[Array[Array[Double]]])]
```

So these can't be added together without digging deeper.